# Laravel - Resource para devolver los datos manipulados

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php7, laravel-6

tengo un proyecto con Laravel 6, con un método que quiero devolver un **resource** ya que quiero manipular algunos de los datos y adaptarlos, para ello tengo por una parte el método.

```
public function list(Request $request)
{
    $user_id = $request->session()->get('user_id');

    $cars2 = UserCar::where('user_id',$user_id)->get();

    $cars =  UserCarResource::collection($cars2);
    
    return view ('front.user.cars.list',compact('cars'));
}
```

Y luego tengo el **resource** como tal

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class UserCarResource extends JsonResource
{


    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {

        return [
            'name' => $this->name . ' test test',
            'model_id' => $this->model_id,
            'model_text' => 'model name',
            'fuelType' => $this->fuelType,
            'fuelType_text' => 'Gasolina',
            'yearFabrication' => $this->yearFabrication,
            'potency' => $this->potency,
            'enabled' => $this->enabled,

        ];
    }
}
```

Como podéis ver el método le digo que me devuelve un Resource aquí

```
 $cars =  UserCarResource::collection($cars2);
```

Pero creo que no esta entrando en el, porque el resultado que me devuelve es este

[image: ma]

Comment: y que es lo que esperabas en el ouput?

Comment: en ningún momento llamas a la funcion `toArray` llamas a `collection` aunque pareciera que tus datos estan en el nodo  `arttributes`

Answer (score 0):

para invocar la funcion `collection` debes de tener una clase `ResourceCollection` además del `JsonResource`.

Pero funcionaria de la misma forma si creas una instancia de `UserCarResurce`, el siguiente código podría solucionar tu problema:

```
 $cars =  new UserCarResource($cars2);
```